# Checking selected date is less than current date with array.every()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function where user selects dates and it gets stored in an **array object**.

There is check to see if user does not select dates that are already passed.

It should ideally allow user to select current date but when I do so it is not working and the check gets triggered.

```
datesArr = [{ date: '05/10/2023' }, { date: '05/11/2023' }];

let result = datesArr.every(({ date }) => {
  return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString() < new Date().toLocaleDateString();
});

console.log(result);

result === false ? promptMessages(`Cannot use an older date.`, 'error') : '';
```

So as per the array, the dates selected by the user should be valid, instead I get the result as false.

I only need to match dates, so time is not relevant.

How do I ensure the current date is not treated as an old date.

Comment: don't convert the date to string, just `return new Date( date ) > new Date()`. (also you're testing the wrong direction, they should be 'greater than' now. Keep in mind that if you don't pass a time it will default to 0 so dates on the same day as today won't pass.

Comment: Hey I tried that and I'm getting the same error, but if I just use new Date(date) the output is the date with default time 05:30:00 as per my timezone and the new Date() will have the current date and time , wouldn't that be considered an older since the time would be ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues with the code you have written is `new Date(date).toLocaleDateString() < new Date().toLocaleDateString()` this will convert your date to a sting and you are converting the strings there, that's incorrect. you cant compare two strings and see the date is greater or less

Also you have to see if the date is not a past date, sees like you have used the comparison operator incorrectly.

The logic I did is

- Take each dates and create a date object. When you create a date object from a date string, it will give a date object with time as zeros. new Date("05/10/2023") is "Wed May 10 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}". Take the time of this particular date.
- Similarly get the current date and set hours to zero, this will give you the [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) of that date.
- Compare these two times.

JavaScript `getTime` will return the number of milliseconds for this date since the epoch, which is defined as the midnight at the beginning of January 1, 1970, UTC. In the time values that we are comparing its against two particular date which has time 00:00:00. Its enough to compare these two times in your case.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
datesArr = [{ date: "05/10/2023" }, { date: "05/11/2023" }];

let result = datesArr.every(({ date }) => new Date(date).getTime() >= new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));

console.log(result);

result === false ? console.log(`Cannot use an older date.`, "error") : "";
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. Could take time to clarify some doubts regarding this, If I just want to compare dates and not time then why in your code there is a comparison with time if I'm factoring in time in the first place. Secondly, dates would be stored in string format eventually, would it be wrong to convert them initially? Thanks.

Comment: @ankitjt The answer for this question is quiet simple. As you said You dont want o compare the times. But always a date object will have a time part. So the best option is to set the time of both the objects to 00:00:00 and compare them. Ideally you are just comparing two date object with same time, so this will work in your case. Updated the answer description a bit, you can have a look

Answer (score 2):

You can use the toISOString but you need to consolidate. If I run the script in my timezone, the 10th at midnight becomes the 9th

```
const now = consolidate(new Date()); 
const consolidate = date => (date.setHours(15,0,0,0), date.toISOString().split("T")[0]);  
let result = datesArr.every(({ date }) => now <= consolidate(new Date(date)));
```

Example

```js
datesArr = [{ date: '05/10/2023' }, { date: '05/11/2023' }];

const consolidate = date => (date.setHours(15,0,0,0), date.toISOString().split("T")[0]);  
const now = consolidate(new Date()); // only need to do this once
let result = datesArr.every(({ date }) => {
console.log(now,consolidate(new Date(date)))
  return now <= consolidate(new Date(date))
});

const message = result ? `Dates are on or in the future from ${now}` :  'Cannot use an older date. Error';

console.log(message);
```

```html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the result of `toLocaleDateString()`, I would compare the integer value using `valueOf` [MDN page for Date.valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf).

Your code would look like this:

```
const datesArr = [{ date: '05/10/2023' }, { date: '05/11/2023' }];
const now = new Date().valueOf();

const result = datesArr.every((date) => new Date(date).valueOf() < now);

console.log(result);

result === false ? promptMessages(`Cannot use an older date.`, 'error') : '';
```

Comment: _This method is functionally equivalent to the Date.prototype.getTime() method and is usually called internally by JavaScript and not explicitly in code._